# Notification like whatsapp or sms app android

Tags: android, notifications, dialog, whatsapp, crouton

I want to create a Notification view just like whatsapp or sms notification.How can i achieve that.

[image]

What I have search till now

**Crouton** : [Can found here](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)

this will show a crouton at running activity and below to the action bar.
if my activity not running or i am on the other activity how can this handle.

**Toast**:
this is not looking like a toast. It show only on bottom or center .

**Dialog**:
this can be done like this but this will blur the application. and disable the background. And i don't want this

Any solution will appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you need is a notification.(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) whats app and all other apps have their own customized notification..if you are looking for a customized notification.i can help you. but I dont understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking in the image above "heads up notificcation" (feature added after android 4.3)

link :[heads up notification](http://techbeasts.com/2014/07/01/get-android-ls-heads-up-notification-on-any-android-4-3-device/)

set priority of notification as high so as to display it on screen head 
hope this helps

Comment: hey how to support it from 4.3 as i thought it is from 5.0 is there any support lib or something please let me know i want that to implement in my app

Comment: heads up are added feature from lollipop..i doubt there is any way you could do it @ pavan

Comment: @ajinkyagaurkar that i know you mentioned after 4.3 so i asked

Answer (score 12):

it's a headsup notification works from android  lollipop
here you check how to show notification you can see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
and for headsup you have to set notification priority as below

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

hope it helps

**EDIT Nov-17**

**Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH** was deprecated in API level 26. use **(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)** instead.

Comment: If you see the screen shot, I have not pull my notification tray. this is happening like
1. Message come Crouton shows then it appears on notification icon on status bar.

Comment: yes it is headsup notification. I will add code as answer. thanks

Comment: Now `Notification.PRIORITY_MAX` is Deprecated.

Comment: Use `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH` or `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX` instead while using notificaion with `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Answer (score 6):

It can be done via Headsup notification. It is feature of Andorid L
so by code here is demo

```
Notification createNotification(boolean makeHeadsUpNotification) {
    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentTitle("Sample Notification")
            .setContentText("This is a normal notification.");

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        notificationBuilder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);
    }
    if (makeHeadsUpNotification) {
        Intent push = new Intent();
        push.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        push.setClass(this, IndexActivity.class);

        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                push, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder
                .setContentText("Heads-Up Notification on Android L or above.")
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);
    }
    return notificationBuilder.build();
}
```

you can call it like

```
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context
           .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification(
           true));
```

Comment: i have a doubt, if the application is closed will i get the notification..?

Comment: @Vishal why not it will, It is a how the notification populate on screen from API 21 and further.