# Firebase push Notification doestnot pop up just showing in the Notification bar

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've written the same code on my `onMessageReceived()` for my FCM service. But when I fire notification from server and if the app is in the background or foreground there is no pop up and the notification is directly shown as an icon in the notification bar.

But when i try in android version 6 i am getting pop up. but when i checked in above 6 then i am not getting `popup`.

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessaging  extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    String title="";
    String message,type,click_action;
    int no_of_messages;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0) {
            message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
            title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            click_action = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");
            no_of_messages++;
            ShowNotification(message);
        }
        else
            Log.i("remoteMessage",message);
    }

    private void ShowNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("loading_flag","load");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        // if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //   notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vadodaramunicipalcorporation);
        //  notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor));
        //  } else {
        //     setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vadodaramunicipalcorporation)
        //  }
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.vadodaramunicipalcorporation)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.vadodaramunicipalcorporation))
            .setContentTitle("You have new "+ title)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setTicker("Hearty365")
            .setContentInfo("Info")
            .setContentText(message+" new Alerts")
            .setNumber(no_of_messages)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Notification

```
{
    "to":"token-key",
    "data" : {
         "body" : "4",
          "title" : "Alert",
          "click_action" : "Activity.DATA_CLICK"
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129799/7666442

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696441/how-to-show-whatsapp-like-popup-notification-when-app-is-in-background

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845583/notification-like-whatsapp-or-sms-app-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a function I have written a while back for showing notifications in Android Oreo and it was working without any problem, you can give it a try if you want.

```
public void createNotification(String aTitle, String aMessage, Intent goToIntent) {
final int NOTIFY_ID = Constants.Notification_ID_1;
String name = "user_channel"; // They are hardcoded only for show it's just strings
String id = "user_channel_1"; // The user-visible name of the channel.
String description = "user_first_channel"; // The user-visible description of the channel.

PendingIntent pendingIntent;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

if (notifManager == null) {
    notifManager =
            (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
    if (mChannel == null) {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);

    goToIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, goToIntent, 0);

    builder.setContentTitle(aTitle)  // required
            .setContentText(aMessage)  // required
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker(aTitle)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
} else {

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    goToIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, goToIntent, 0);

    builder.setContentTitle(aTitle)    // required
            .setContentText(aMessage)  // required
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker(aTitle)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
}

Notification notification = builder.build();
notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
}
```